# Возможно ли передавать звуковые сообщения через websocket

Tags: php, angularjs, websocket, аудио

Нужно передавать голос в режиме реального времени через протокол socket.io или подобную технологию. Есть Apache сервер с php и клиент на Angular. Нужно Сделать что-бы клиент мог общаться с другим клиентом. Вот задумался реально ли это и каким образом реализовать?

Comment: Возможно вас заинтересует технология WebRTC. Правда ее пока не все браузеры поддерживают, коммерческие сервисы для работы со звуком на сайте комбинирует флешь и WebRTC.

Comment: @cheops куда большая проблема с WebRTC это невозможность установления прямых соединений (которая, как я выяснил на практике, часто встречается) и средства обхода этой проблемы (TURN). Поддержка браузерами "сравнительно нормальная".

Comment: @D-side а есть примеры для тестовой реализации аудиосвязи?

Comment: @modelfak полно, даже больше, чем чатиков, а пробовал я именно чатик: для чатиков нужен `DataChannel`, который пока не везде есть.